# Fast way to compute matrix of the from (Matrix - constant)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

I would like to find a faster way to compute the matrix `v`. Note that if height = width then the matrix v is symmetric, `v = v.T`. The width and the height are arbitrary positive integers.

```
v = np.zeros((height, width)) # rows columns

# region center
cr = np.round(height / 2)
cc = np.round(width / 2)

# there has to be a quicker way to do this
for w in range(width):
    v[:, w] = [np.sqrt((w - cc) ** 2 + (h - cr) ** 2) for h in range(height)]
```

Comment: I don't know what to call this operation, but it doesn't appear to have something to do with the L2 norm of a matrix, which is the largest eigenvalue magnitude. Maybe the title should be adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
out = np.sqrt((np.arange(width)-cc)**2 + (np.arange(height)[:,None]-cr)**2)
```

---

```
width=5
height=8
v = np.zeros((height, width)) # rows columns
# region center
cr = np.round(height / 2)
cc = np.round(width / 2)
# there has to be a quicker way to do this
for w in range(width):
    v[:, w] = [np.sqrt((w - cc) ** 2 + (h - cr) ** 2) for h in range(height)]

np.allclose(v, out)
# True
```

Comment: This answer was ~2x as fast as @alain T. 's answer. Totally forgot about numpy broadcasting.

Comment: I forgot about it too

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), with [`numpy.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

shape = (height, width)
v = cdist(np.indices(shape).reshape(2, -1).T, [[cr, cc]]).reshape(shape)
```

This yields identical results to [@yatu's broadcasting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61622209/2988730) in all cases, but strangely is ~3x slower for a large variety of input sizes. That being said, it is likely a bit more space efficient, since it allocates only one array of the output size rather than two (second one being the sum fed into the square root). This should not be a consideration for any normal input you encounter, so use the broadcasting solution. This is just here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any loop.  Generate a matrix of row indexes and a matrix of column indexes and apply the formula between the two matrices:

```
rows,cols = np.indices((height,width))
v         = np.sqrt((rows-height//2)**2+(cols-width//2)**2)
```